# Error page (runtime error) on query page on data.SE?

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

Viewing [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1767/all-answers-containing-same-problem) gives me the following:

http://phpcode.eu/images/1315506104.php

However it displays fine when not logged in:

[image]

Is that a bug? Should it be fixed?

Comment: Looks like a Chrome issue.  Works fine for me in IE 8.

Comment: @JNK: no. Try to log in and it won't work

Comment: Reproduced on chromium (14.0) & firefox (6) on linux, only while logged in

Comment: @Genesis - that explains it, I use chrome primarily so IE didnt have my credentials

Comment: @Mat: yes, "However works fine when unlogged"

Comment: @genesis: indeed fine when logged out. Same for opera, except that one shows a "page not found" page when logged in.

Comment: Additional confirmation of error -- happening on Chrome 13 in Windows.

Comment: We're looking into it.

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff: thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We missed a spot that needed updating due to some maintenance we did earlier today.  All systems are a-go now! (: